# Identify duplicate user login on a distributed JavaEE application

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, servlet-filters, jboss5.x

We have an application where user login is implemented using JavaEE5 Servlets, Filters, Spring3.0 and SQL Server database tables. When a user logs into the application, a record on User database table is added against the user. If any other user logs in whist the first user already logged in with same login credentials, we either avoid it or allow it depending on some conditions. This is made easy because of having single database table recording all user logins. I'm wondering  if there is any way to avoid database and rely on application server. We are using JBoss5.1 currently.